# RequiredValidator for Drop Down not firing (asp:dropdown populated from database)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

```
<asp:DropDownList id="Code1" runat="server" 
    OnLoad="GetCode1" ValidationGroup="ValidateGroup"/>    
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Code1_RequiredValidator" runat="server" 
       ErrorMessage="Please select a value!"   ControlToValidate="Code1" 
       ValidationGroup="ValidateGroup" InitialValue="Select Code1!">
 </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

the drop down is populated in the code behind as shown below:

```
protected void GetCode1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ISROManagement sroMgmt = ObjectFactory.CreateSROManagement();
                List<string> code1List = QuerydBForCodes();
                Code1.DataSource = codeList;
                Code1.DataBind();
                Code1.Items.Insert(0, "Make a selection."); //Added to be shown as the default value:
            }
        }
```

When I submit the modal pop up extender -with the default value at index 0 i.e. Make a Selection - I don't see the ErrorMessage="Please make a selection!" printed next to the drop down! So the validation does not happen.

Also in the button click which submits the modal pop up, i have a

```
Page.Validate("ValidateGroup");
        if (!Page.IsValid) return;
```

However, I dont see the validation message printed next to the drop down!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your drop down list must have the same ValidationGroup. Add ValidationGroup="ValidateGroup" to your drop down list

Change InitialValue from "Select Code1!" to "Make a selection."

Comment: this is not help trigger the required field validator

Comment: @user1216456 - Your button needs to have same validation group as well. If that doesnt work try Try autopostback="true" on drop down list

Comment: tried the same validation group on the button and also the autopostback=true with no change. Still the RequiredFieldValidator does not fire.

Comment: @user1216456 - I tried your sample and it works now. Change InitialValue="Make a selection.". I have updated answer. Basically initial value must match your default dropdownlist value. If it solves your problem please mark it as answer and +1 for my efforts

Answer (score 1):

In GetCode1 function replace following line:

```
Code1.Items.Insert(0, "Make a selection.");
```

To

```
Code1.Items.Insert(0, "");
```